# The specified file could not be found when i run a file.exe

Tags: c, cmd, exe

When I use this

```
comparer.exe <test_comparer24_1>.bmp <test_comparer24_2>.bmp
```

in cmd, this error show up

> The specified file could not be found

even thought I have the bmp files in the same folder. This is the part of code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Use the format: %s <filename1>.bmp <filename2>.bmp\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    return BMPComparer(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

any ideas to help me figure this out ?

Comment: It looke like the program is expecting you to enter the filenames without the `.bmp` extension, and you definitely don't need the angle brackets. Try `comparer.exe test_comparer24_1 test_comparer24_2` instead

Comment: i tried that and it give me another error of File dosen't exist

Comment: can you add a function definition for BMPComparer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<` and `>` characters are likely included in the help text to indicate that you should replace the contents.

The characters `<` and `>` have a special function on most shells and are called [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

Please try your command without the `<` and `>` characters:

```
comparer.exe test_comparer24_1.bmp test_comparer24_2.bmp
```